# Firemonkey controls do not draw

Tags: delphi, components, firemonkey

I simply can't figure out what I'm doing wrong when trying to paint a control.

I've tried using TCanvas.BeginScene()/TCanvas.EndScene(), tried painting in other methods (for example main form OnPaint()).
I've tried TControl.InvalidateRect().
I get nothing.

Here's what I have in my test app:

```
type
  TTestControl = class(TControl)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    fTestControl: TTestControl;
  end;

procedure TTestControl.Paint;
begin
  Canvas.Fill.Color := TColorRec.Blueviolet;
  Canvas.FillEllipse(ClipRect, AbsoluteOpacity);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  fTestControl := TTestControl.Create(Self);
  fTestControl.Parent := Self;
  fTestControl.Align  := TAlignLayout.Client;
end;
```

It ought to be enough, according to what's online.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Canvas.Fill.Color` is a `TAlphaColor`.

Change the line

```
  Canvas.Fill.Color := TColorRec.Blueviolet;
```

to

```
  Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Blueviolet;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Paint methods should be like this:

```
procedure TTestControl.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  Canvas.BeginScene;
  Canvas.Fill.Color := claBlueviolet;
  Canvas.FillEllipse(ClipRect, AbsoluteOpacity);
  Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

I, also, think you should override the DoPaint method of TControl and not the Paint.

Comment: Actually it should have a `try` / `finally` block along with it. But that wouldn't fix this issue.

Comment: I believe they are superfluous in TControl.Paint, because they're already done elsewhere in the FMX code.